# PreBuild target executes everytime, even when no file changed

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

In the process of upgrading a solution to the new SDK-style format, I noticed that the PreBuild target was executing everytime, even when no file changed. In classic projects, I used the PreBuildEvent element, and it worked perfectly, executing only when a file changed. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues?q=is%3Aissue+prebuild Sounds like a good question for the developers.

Comment: Hi @Max Toro, do you mean the second time you click to `Build`(not `Rebuild`) the project, without changing anything, in new SDK-style project, the PreBuild target will run again? If so, does Output window show `1 up-to-date`?

Comment: Did a simple test on my side, used a non sdk and a new sdk project, and set the PreBuild target, the PreBuild target only ran once when I built the project and without changing anything, on the second `Build` it successfully skipped. Also tested by converting/upgrading the non sdk project to the new sdk project(used [try-convert](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert)), same result. I may suggest you try to clear the cache first, such as `.bin`, `.obj`, `.vs` folders.

Comment: MSBuild will always execute the target no matter if new/old csproj, the new project system in VS has a heuristic to determine wether or not to call msbuild. you can increase its log level (tools->options->sdk-style projects->up to date checks->logging level) to see why it deemed it necessary to call msbuild.

Comment: You can also write your target using Inputs and Outputs to skip executing its steps if none of your inputs change - see [How to: Build Incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally) for more details

Comment: I agree with Martin, Martin’s suggestions are very helpful. Just add one missing point, tools > options > **Projects and Solutions** > SDK-Style Projects > …

Comment: @MartinUllrich Logging tells me that the generated file (a C# .cs file) changed after last up-to-date check. I'm using UpToDateCheckInput and UpToDateCheckOutput, but not using Inputs and Outputs on the target.

Comment: Well if your MSBuild target always executes and modifies the files (timestamps) then the project system heuristic will see the project changes as well. You need to make sure your MSBuild targets are incremental (no file timestamp changes if no change is made to the project), then UpToDateCheckInput/Output can be used to configure the additional project system level heuristig preventing unnecessary calls to msbuild

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thank you. Making progress. I've posted a new question, appreciate your input https://stackoverflow.com/q/69397117/39923

Answer (score 0):

two reasons i stumbled upon:

1. project contains files not found (e.g. an orphaned .h or .cpp file in the project files list)
2. duplicate entries in the vcprojx :

> ```
> <PostBuildEvent />
> <PreBuildEvent />
> <PostBuildEvent />
> ```

followed by steps with content, e.g.:

> ```
>  <PreBuildEvent>
>       <Command>$(CopyDLL) </Command>
>  </PreBuildEvent>
> ```

removing those lines fixed it (VS2019 tested)

both reasons triggered unnecessary rebuilds

Comment: Point 2. maybe incorrect as it is not observed in all project files. Some still had those entries and did not recompile.